# How to calculate relative permittivity from the following chart

Tags: complex-numbers, radar

[image: Material property]
So basically, I was using HFSS to run some simulation on a MnZn absorber https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-Real-and-b-imaginary-dielectric-permittivity-curves-for-RAM-based-on-MnZn-ferrite_fig1_260363537
I have chart above detailing the characteristics of the material which include: real permittivity , imaginary permittivity , real permeability, imaginary permeability.
However, what I need for HFSS is "**relative permittivity**"
How do I calculate it?
The way I currently do it is that i would input the real permittivity and imaginary permittivity into an excel chart to find out their complex absolute permittivity. For example: let say my real permittivity is 4 and Imaginary permittivity is 1 => absolute permittivity will be √(4^2+1^2) = 4.12
Then I input this absolute value into HFSS. But I'm not entirely sure if that is the correct way
[image: excel table]

Answer (score 0):

Relative permitivity is equal to absolute permitivity divided by that of the vacuum:

$$\epsilon_r = \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon_0}$$

Therefore, you need to divide every value you calculated by $\epsilon_0 \approx 8.85 \times 10^{-12} \, F/m$. For instance, distilled water has relative permitivity equal to 80 (no units), meaning its permitivity is 80 times the one of the vacuum.